# Is it possible to commit a change to the current branch and push the same change to a branch in a different project?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I need an advice in regards to this scenario.

"We have a front-end project (A) that need to be duplicated or branched from now to another project (B). New features that we will need to apply to A sometimes are needed in B as well and sometimes not and viceversa."

Which can be the best solution?

1 - Keep one project and have 2 branches (C,D). When we commit to branch D we push the change to 
both branches C and D.

2 - Have two different projects. When we commit a change to A and we want it on B as well we need to remember to copy and paste the change to the project B.

What I'm asking is, can I go for solution number 2 but when I push a change to the current project A, I would like to push the change to the project B as well via SourceTree/git command.

Are there any other better solutions that can be applied?

Hope it's clear enough.

Thanks in advance.
Fabio

Comment: if you have 2 different projects as you describe, git has no idea about their relations.  You need to do your own scripting to provide needed operation of syncing  files, branching, merges between projects, ... It is possible, but might not be easy.

Comment: Ask yourself: Is it possible and feasible to encapsulate the changes so that they can be implemented in only one project while not polluting the other? If yes, implement changes like feature plugs, that can be easily enabled or disabled. If not, make a hard fork and just reimplement them - refactor inidividually. Trying to synchronize two projects that follow different requirements will result in chaos and a big ball of mud.